# switch db without authentication in PHP mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using php MongoClient() to login (auth=true) to mongodb "test" using Php.
Now I want to switch db to "test1" using php without authentication.
It works fine with mongo shell command - "use test1"
When I try to do the same in php using connection->selectdb("test1"), it tries to authenticate the same user on "test1" db and fails.

Is there a way to switch db using Php Mongoclient()?

The below code on mongoshell will authenticate user1 on test and run mapreduce on test1.orders by storing the result in test.SampleGroupby

```
mongo --host XXXX -u user1 -p XXXX --authenticationDatabase test
 use test1;  /*I don't need to authenticate user1 on test1 (test.user1 already has read/write permission on test1) */
 db.orders.mapReduce(mapf, redf, {"out": {reduce: "SampleGroupby", db: "test"}, finalize: finf })
```

Now the same I want to achieve using php -

```
$Connection = MongoClient("mongodb://XXXX:XXXX", array("username" => user1, "password" => XXXX, "db" => test));
$Connection->test1->command(array(     /*Here it tries to re authenticate user1 on test1 and fails */
"mapreduce" => orders,
"map" => $map,
"reduce" => $reduce,
"out" => array("reduce" => SampleGroupby , "db" => test),
"finalize" => $finalize
));
```

Answer (score 0):

**MongoClient** is PHP class utilized for connection to **MongoDB** host with connection string as argument.
Connection string encapsulates username,password and Mongodb host.

If MongoDB is configured to enable authentication then only username and password are required in connection string

Eg.**mongodb://username:password@host:port**

**MongoClient** will return database connection object.

Using database connection object we switch to specific database using **selectDB**() method.

Eg.

```
$conn = new MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@host:port'); 
$db = $conn->selectDB("dbname");
```

If authentication is enabled then there will be a separate user per database.

Hence for switching to another database then we need to define a new connection object using **MongoClient** with connection string as argument and then invoke **selectDB**() method using returned connection object

Without authentication enabled we  just need to invoke selectDB() method with database name as argument

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got the point but the problem here is that I am not able to achieve the same result I can get using mongo shell. Updated question with exact scenario.